# Cannot find module 'react' when use third party React UI lib - Vite + Preact

Tags: javascript, vite, preact, testing-library, vitest

I'm facing this issue in this Vite started repository.

https://github.com/vicainelli/vite-starter

I'm using Vite + Preact + Vitest + Testing Library

If I'm testing any code inside the codebase, it works fine, but If the test runs against some component that uses another component from an external library, I'm getting this error.

```sh
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Suites 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

 FAIL  src/components/Button.test.js [ src/components/Button.test.js ]
 ❯ Object.<anonymous> node_modules/@mantine/styles/cjs/theme/MantineProvider.js:5:13

Test Files  1 failed | 1 passed (2)
     Tests  2 passed (2)
Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/vite-starter/vite-starter/node_modules/@mantine/styles/cjs/theme/MantineProvider.js
- /home/runner/work/vite-starter/vite-starter/node_modules/@mantine/styles/cjs/index.js
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/1]⎯
```

This is something similar to [this issue](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/980), but I'm already using preact/compact, so, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like an issue for their tracker. It seems you intended to link to something ("[this issue") but haven't. You're also duplicating the aliases for some reason (`@preact/preset-vite` ships with this) and your `includes` isn't meaningfully different from the default either. Both should probably be removed.

Comment: Hey @rschristian, I update the post with the issue link, what did you mean with the `includes`?

Comment: Thanks, that issue actually gives a lot of context (and tells you the solution). What I mean about the `include` is that it's not meaningfully different so there's really no reason to be setting it. [This is the default](https://github.com/preactjs/preset-vite/blob/095c735b03b6b021262829a8ced2cb53c0877df5/src/index.ts#L75), yours is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to run the following:

```sh
yarn add react@npm:@preact/compat react-dom@npm:@preact/compat
```

Seems like Vitest cannot effectively alias.